# Infer context generic type from the nearest provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have a context used by components that display data and also allow editing of that data. I chose to make this a context instead of just a hook because sometimes I have nested components that also need the state and I don't want to keep prop drilling. I want this to be generic and I have it working as is.

```js
// DataEditingContextProvider.tsx

export interface DataEditingContextType<T extends object> {
  editing: boolean;
  data: T;
  // ...
}

export const DataEditingContext = createContext<DataEditingContextType<any>>(
  {} as DataEditingContextType<any>
);

export function DataEditingContextProvider<T extends object>({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState<T>({} as T);
  // ...

  return (
    <DataEditingContext.Provider value={{ editing, setEditing, data }}>
      {children}
    </DataEditingContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```js
// withDataEditingContext.tsx

export function withDataEditingContext<
  T extends object,
  P extends object
>(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>) {
  return (props: P) => {
    return (
      <DataEditingContextProvider<T>>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </DataEditingContextProvider>
    );
  };
}
```

```js
// useDataEditingContext.tsx

export function useDataEditingContext<T extends object>() {
  return useContext<DataEditingContext<T>>(DataEditingContext);
}
```

```js
// MyDataEditingComponent.tsx

interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

function MyComponent() {
  const { editing, data } = useDataEditingContext<User>();
  // ...
}

export const MyDataEditingComponent = withDataEditingContext<User>(MyComponent);
```

The issue I am trying to solve now is in `useDataEditingContext`. Currently, the caller must supply the type like `useDataEditingContext<User>()` which I feel is redundant because the type is already set on `withDataEditingContext`. If I drop the type in `useDataEditingContext()`, the type of `data` just becomes `any`, or worse, the caller could supply a different type `useDataEditingContext<Foo>()`.

Ideally, I would like to not have to pass they type in `useDataEditingContext` and infer it based on the nearest provider. Or at the very least, throw an error if the type supplied does not match.

I've seen examples of using a factory function to create the context like [here](https://blog.ordina-jworks.io/architecture/2021/02/12/react-generic-context.html), but that's too much overhead just to use the context.

Comment: From your problem description, it seem to me that you would benefit more from a library like [jotai](https://jotai.org/) or [zustand](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/getting-started/introduction). Have you explored these options? Is there a specific reason for using a React context as opposed to something like Jotai, which allowes you to have shared editable state.

Comment: @Juraj This is for a library I am making. I don't want to use other libraries in my library.

Comment: @Juraj Also, the links you provided seem to be for global state management. The state used in my component really only applies to a small section. An example use case is for a row in a table that allows editing the data. Each row has it's own DataEditingContext.

Comment: In that case, the solution you are looking for isn't possible. As @Ahmed described in his answer. Although if the context is only used in small sections (row of a table), I would avoid it all together. Context is really meant to be a read-only share of state, mostly throughout larger sections.

If you want your users to have easier access to the row data (they are rendering it) you have to pass them the context consumer, and if you are doing that, you can pass the data just as easily.

If it is only internal. The complexity this would bring, is much greater than a few props.

Comment: Yeah, when I started this, context seemed like a good idea, but now it seems unnecessary. I will probably just convert this to a hook instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're describing can't be solved by the solution you're looking for. TypeScript doesn't know where this function is called.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const { editing, data } = useDataEditingContext<User>();
  // ...
}

export const MyDataEditingComponent = withDataEditingContext<User>(MyComponent);
```

Consider the previous snippet, you're expecting from TypeScript to infer the type in the second line from the last line. that's not possible.

The solution I can propose is to create an initialization utility that takes the type once and return a typed hook as well as a wrapper.

```
// this function is intended to be used outside of the component

export function createEditingContext<T extends object>() {
  function useDataEditingContext() {
    return useContext<DataEditingContext<T>>(DataEditingContext);
  }

  function withDataEditingContext<
    P extends object
  >(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>) {
    return (props: P) => {
      return (
        <DataEditingContextProvider<T>>
          <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </DataEditingContextProvider>
      );
    };
  }

  return [useDataEditingContext, withDataEditingContext] as const;
  
  // or (if you'd like to have the same names)
  return { useDataEditingContext, withDataEditingContext };
}
```

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

const [useDataEditingContext, withDataEditingContext] = createEditingContext<User>();

function MyComponent() {
  const { editing, data } = useDataEditingContext<User>();
  // ...
}

export const MyDataEditingComponent = withDataEditingContext<User>(MyComponent);
```

Now both of the hook and the HOC, inherit the same type from the initialization.

---

You can also use [TypeScript Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)